# Replace methode for a custom type array in golang

Tags: arrays, go

I am trying to add or replace (or add) a field in a custom type that is nothing but an array of structs based on a struct field. Basically something simple, have a look here:

https://play.golang.org/p/Fb04g4Oq1C

Line 15 is where I am struggling. The compiler does not get to the array behind my type and does not want to address the array values by there index. How can I achieve that the given part of the array will be replaced?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
*v[i] = n
```

with

```
(*v)[i] = n
```

The former means "take what `v[i]` points to", while the latter, "take what `v` points to and take `i`'th element".

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279292/6309), a slice is already a kind of pointer, rendering a pointer to a slice totally useless.

That means a version of your code using `[]` instead of a pointer to `[]` works just fine.
See [this example](https://play.golang.org/p/8NciIcayKs):

```
func (v VarBucket) AddOrReplace(n Var) VarBucket {
    for i, vars := range v {
        if vars.Name == n.Name {
            v[i] = n
            fmt.Println("Replaced")
            return v
        }
    }
    v = append(v, n)
    fmt.Println("Added")
    return v
}
```

With:

```
v_a := Var{Name: "a", Value: "A"}
v_b := Var{Name: "b", Value: "B"}
v_c := Var{Name: "a", Value: "C"}

b := VarBucket{}
b = b.AddOrReplace(v_a) // add
fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)
b = b.AddOrReplace(v_b) // add
fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)
b = b.AddOrReplace(v_c) // replace v_a
fmt.Printf("%v\n", b)
```

Output:

```
Added
[{a A}]
Added
[{a A} {b B}]
Replaced
[{a C} {b B}]
```