# Variable defined in Golang

Tags: go

I create a var of type

```
var RespData   []ResponseData

type ResponseData struct {
   DataType       string      
   Component      string      
   ParameterName  string      
   ParameterValue string      
   TableValue     *[]Rows 
}

type TabRow struct {
   ColName     string 
   ColValue    string 
   ColDataType string 
}

type Rows *[]TabRow
```

I want to fill `TableValue` of type `*[]Rows`.
Can you please tell me with an example by assigning any values in the `TableValue`.

Comment: Fill it with what? Can you show us what you're trying to do that currently isn't working?

Comment: Or maybe you have some example data? You can't fill TableValue without creating a ResponseData object. What else do you want to go in there?

Answer (score 1):

[Slices are reference type](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#slices) (it is already a [kind of pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279292/6309)), so you don't need a pointer to a slice (`*[]Rows`).

You can use a slice of slices though `TableValue []Rows`, with `Rows` being a slice of pointers to `TabRow`: `Rows []*TabRow`.

```
tr11 := &TabRow{ColName: "cname11", ColValue: "cv11", ColDataType: "cd11"}
tr12 := &TabRow{ColName: "cname12", ColValue: "cv12", ColDataType: "cd12"}
row1 := Rows{tr11, tr12}
rd := &ResponseData{TableValue: []Rows{row1}}
fmt.Printf("%+v", rd )
```

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/7HFx0E2J3U).

Comment: I am filling like this 

  tr1 := &dal.TabRow{
       ColName:"V",
       ColValue:"G",
       ColDataType:"St",
      }                                                                           row1 := Rows{tr1,}

respdata := ResponseData{
        DataType       : "Table",
        Component      : "",
        ParameterName  : "",
        ParameterValue : "",
        TableValue     : []Rows{row1,},
 }                                                                                                                  
This way I am getting error please correct me.

Comment: @Rishabhsharma did you change your type definition as I did in http://play.golang.org/p/7HFx0E2J3U?