# Replace a single string in a slice for a group of strings

Tags: go, slice

I want to have a slice of strings, and when certain strings are found, they are replaced by a group of related strings.

For instance, if I have this :

```
[]string{"A","FROM_B_TO_E","F"}
```

After my method runs I want to have :

```
[]string{"A","B","C","D","E","F"}
```

I came up with this code, the thing is, although I can print my **to_be_added** slice just before actually adding it, for some reason it does not work. It does work however if I change my **translateRule** so instead of returning a slice of string it only returns a single string :

```
  func groupRules(validationRules []string){
        for index,rulename := range validationRules {
            if succeeded, to_be_added := translateRule(rulename) ; succeeded == true{
                fmt.Println("Entro! ", to_be_added)
                validationRules = append(append(validationRules[:index],to_be_added...), validationRules[index+1:]...)
            }
        }
    }
    func translateRule(rule string) ( bool , []string ) {
        if rule == "rs_full" {
            return true,[]string{"sapo","rana"}
        }
        return false,nil
    }
```

Comment: You should pass a pointer func groupRules(validationRules *[]string)

Comment: @Uvelichitel I don't think so. You dont need to pass a pointer when sending a slice since it gets deferred by default. Also, as I commented on my note, if I to_be_added is a string instead of a []string it works perfectly

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: slices are values like everything else, and if you want to modify the argument you need a pointer to it. You can overwrite values within the slice, but the slice value is only a copy.

Comment: Use the same approach `append` does, return the new slice and reassign it to the original variable.

Comment: @JimB I actually tried using a pointer. Here is the reason why I cannot and should not : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278023/golang-cannot-range-over-pointer-to-slice

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: that's not relevant here. Appending to an array modifies it, so you need a pointer in order for that to be reflected outside the function.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/E_1GH6r4f87

Comment: @mkopriva Check this : https://play.golang.org/p/rTlrh_SbKkK . As soon as I try to slice one of those pointers, it fails. And I need to split the slice in order to accomplish this. Thats why I am insisting in that I cannot use this approach. If you can somehow modify my code using pointers and getting it to work Ill slute you and admit I was wrong

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ZZKFwve1TNi the `s[:]` is evaluated first, so Go thinks you're trying to slice a pointer, use parens to change the order of evaluation. Or do it in two steps https://play.golang.org/p/nmQPiPpwruW.

Comment: or do what most Go code does, and return the new slice rather than taking a pointer to a slice.

Comment: @JimB Nor the pointers or the "just pass it" worked. So I actually ended up doing exactly that and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

So, my lack of Go experience or the bad code I write lead me to this :

```
func groupRules(validationRules []string) []string{
    var tmp_slice []string
    for _ ,rulename := range validationRules {
        if succeeded, to_be_added := translateRule(rulename) ; succeeded == true{
            tmp_slice = append(tmp_slice,to_be_added...)
        }else{
            tmp_slice = append(tmp_slice,rulename)
        }
    }
    return tmp_slice
}
func translateRule(rule string) ( bool , []string ) {
    if rule == "rs_full" {
        return true,[]string{"sapo","rana","tigre"}
    }
    return false,nil
}
```

Now it works flawlessly.

Thank you all.